# Generating one time use 2FA accounts error

Tags: cold-storage

When trying to generate cold wallets using the "Ice Cold Storage, One-Time-Use 2FA Account"; I ran into an error when trying to generate the address.  I created a randomly generated address first, but when I try to put in the 'public address' and combine it with a 2FA key it gives me this error

```
ReferenceError: CRYPTONOTE_PUBLIC_SUBADDRESS_BASE58_PREFIX is not defined
```

The public address I used was:

```
44e9dLBemiQRGsAgRRziBjZsCSsfNVenJEv3aRmYKR6h7XtCbUerVUC2epkxDWN4Nd1ZAw5edtnzWgubd1HXBaq21BBvcFD
```

and the 2FA key I chose was just:

```
random
```

Am I supposed to be inputing another type of public address?

Edit: I am using https://xmr.llcoins.net/

Comment: That looks like an error in the code. It might be loaded outdated references. Clear cache, force reload, see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

By putting "random" in box 10 and your address in box 11, it successfully generate a new address.
Do you still have the problem? Are you filling the same boxes?

By the way I was using the site online, which is absolutely to avoid when using the redeem function.